# Upload a file to public_html folder

Tags: php, file-upload, joomla, public-html

I have a joomla component that fetches the audio songs from the music folder on the server and plays them in the front end. And the users can upload their songs from the front end.

But the problem is that, the component settings are such that the music folder path must be outside of the web root.

The path looks like:

> /home/username/public_html/audio

But i am confused how to upload the files to a location inside 'public_html' folder, using php. What should be the destination address that i can use in my code?

Comment: Isn't it the norm to upload the files (e.g. images) inside `public_html` so that they are publicly accessible? What error do you get if you set the full path in the upload script?

Comment: ok, i see that the 'public_html' folder on server resembles the 'www' or the webroot of the domain. So i will try to upload the file normally.

Comment: What is the name of the component?

Comment: i remember the component name is: Maian media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the server path in the Joomla environment:

```
echo JPATH_SITE;
```

[Examples of usage](http://www.latenight-coding.com/joomla-faqs/developers/get-path-joomla-folder.html)